# What Is the Approximation of the Series (Index and Radicand in A.P)?

Tags: inequality, approximation

I tried to approximate $\displaystyle\bigg\lfloor \sum^{10}_{n=2}n^{\frac{1}{12-n}}\bigg\rfloor$ using inequality.

My try was,

$\sqrt[n-k+1]{k-1}<\sqrt[n-k]{k}<\sqrt[n-k-1]{k+1}$

So,

$7\sqrt[12]{2}<\displaystyle\sum^{10}_{n=2}n^{\frac{1}{12-n}}<7\sqrt{12}$

$\displaystyle 8\leq\bigg\lfloor \sum^{10}_{n=2}n^{\frac{1}{12-n}}\bigg\rfloor\leq24$

So, is there a way to approximate it more accurately?

Comment: You can have a better lower bound since the summand is increasing with $n$. So, $\lfloor 9 \times 2^{\frac 1 {10}} \rfloor=9$ is better

Comment: Thank you. May I ask you if there's a name for this approximation?

Comment: There is no approximation at all. Each term is larger than the previous one. So ... ?

Comment: Thank you. I just understood.

Comment: @Account Any information about the question (e.g. source)?